# The procedure entry point upigbp could not be located in the dynamic link library OCI.dll - xampp - v 3.2.1

Tags: php, oracle, apache, dll, xampp

I have installed XAMPP - v3.2.1 on my window 7 machine. Every time i start APACHE from XAMPP control panel, it is showing error pop up like this:

> The procedure entry point upigbp could not be located in the dynamic
>   link library OCI.dll

I have installed oracle version 11 on my machine.

Because of this db operations are not working already uncommented `extension=php_oci8_11g.dll` in `php.ini`

Can anyone help me with this ?